# My Canvas App keeps refreshing

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using this code for my App to allow the users to login as well as get the app permissions to create and edit the user's events, and it was working fine, but when I tried it today the page keeps refreshing infinity as well as changes the auth code each time. I can't tell what is going on.

```
<?php
   // Include facebook php api 
   require_once("lib/facebook.php");

    // Setup app configuration
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'APP_ID';
    $config['secret'] = 'APP_SECRET';
    $config['cookie'] = true;
    $config['fileUpload'] = true;

    // set app id & canvas page for location variable
    $app_id = 'APP_ID';
    $canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/mixityhc/";

      $location = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
         . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=publish_stream,email,create_event,rsvp_event,user_events,friends_events";

  // create new instance of facebook object
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    // Get user id
    $fbID = $facebook->getUser();

    // Get the current access token
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    // check if we have valid user
 if ($fbID) {
     try {
          // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
         $fb_user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');   

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          $fbID = NULL;
          // seems we don't have enough permissions
          // we use javascript to redirect user instead of header() due to Facebook bug
          print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';

         // kill the code so nothing else will happen before user gives us permissions
         die();
      }

  } else {
      // seems our user hasn't logged in, redirect him to a FB login page

     print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';

     // kill the code so nothing else will happen before user gives us permissions
     die();
 }

 // Get user email address
 $email = $fb_user_profile['email'];
```

Any help would be much appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The Facebook API was updated to fix an apparent bug in Facebook. So I uploaded the new files (specifically the cert) and it worked. Just in case some one else is having the same problem.

Thanks